# Cannot get Thrustmaster Racing Wheel to work in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, 16.04, gamepad, xbox-360

I'm trying to get an old Thrustmaster Racing Wheel to work under Ubuntu 16.04 running xboxdrv.

lsusb looks OK:

```
lsusb        
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 044f:b653 ThrustMaster, Inc. RGT Force Feedback Clutch Racing Wheel
```

When starting xboxdrv I got this error:

```
sudo xboxdrv -s --device-name "Razer Onza TE" --device-by-id 044f:b653 --type xbox360 --deadzone 4000 --dpad-as-button --trigger-as-button --ui-axismap "x2=REL_X:10,y2=REL_Y:10,x1=KEY_A:KEY_D,y1=KEY_W:KEY_S" --ui-buttonmap "tl=KEY_LEFTSHIFT,tr=KEY_LEFTCTRL" --ui-buttonmap "a=KEY_SPACE,b=KEY_C,x=KEY_1,y=KEY_R" --ui-buttonmap "lb=KEY_Q,rb=KEY_E" --ui-buttonmap "lt=BTN_LEFT,rt=BTN_RIGHT" --ui-buttonmap "dl=KEY_4,dr=KEY_B,du=BTN_MIDDLE,dd=KEY_TAB" --ui-buttonmap "back=KEY_ESC,start=KEY_ENTER"
xboxdrv 0.8.5 - http://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/xboxdrv/ 
Copyright © 2008-2011 Ingo Ruhnke <grumbel@gmx.de> 
Licensed under GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html> 
This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. 
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details. 

Controller:        unknown
Vendor/Product:    044f:b653
USB Path:          001:010
Controller Type:   Xbox360

-- [ ERROR ] ------------------------------------------------------
USBController::usb_find_ep(): couldn't find matching endpoint
```

P.S. I connected only the Wheel, pedals are still disconnected.

Comment: Post the whole output of `lsusb -v -d 044f:b653`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked at manufacturer's website and I found that Thrustmaster official drivers support Windows only (Windows 10 maximum).
Possibly, the wheel could be installed on Linux too, but using the original drivers over Windows is good option.

Answer (score 0):

You need [tmdrv](https://github.com/her001/tmdrv)  to set the wheel to the proper mode for input(HID) system to recognize it as `/dev/input/js0`.

First git-clone its repo and install it in a venv by typing the following bash commands.

```bsh
####
## Setup (done only once)
##
## Clone the Thrustmaster-driver repo.
#
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/her001/tmdrv tmdrv.git
cd !$

## Install `libusb1` dep in a venv.
#
python3 -m venv --prompt tmdrv .venv
.venv/bin/activate
pip install libusb1

## Get the list of supported wheels and select yours,
## to use it on the next command.
./tmdrv.py -D
```

Then, every time you plug the wheel-joystick in the USB, you would have to issue this command as *root*:

```bsh
## After every plugging--of-wheel 
sudo /.../tmdrv.git/.venv/bin/python tmdrv.py -d <selected-wheel-above>
```

Read [this recipe](https://github.com/vpelletier/python-libusb1/issues/34#issuecomment-369575778) if you don't want to use root(`sudo`) to write IO into USB.